# Extracting data from combobox filled with items from sharepoint

Tags: powerapps

I have a form that contains a combobox field that has options taken from a sharepoint list. The data type is listed as an item, and the function is Choices([@'Name'].ColumnName). I would like to extract the single selected value and convert it into text. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is. But without more information this question will be difficult to answer. What have you tried so far. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is easily done.

**It looks like:**

- You have a Sharepoint list
- With a Person-type column
- Then you added a Form control to your PowerApps
- And now you want to get like, `DisplayName` or `JobTitle` from the Combobox.

Because Person-type columns are really record of information, you have to use "dot notation" to get a level deeper.

**Try this:**

- Add a Label control to your PowerApp
- Set its `Text` proptery to `<yourComboboxNameHere>.Selected.DisplayName`

In the above example, `Selected` is the record, `DisplayName` is the column.

By adding the "." after `Selected`, you can see all available options.

**Example in action:**

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. The DisplayName worked for me for the ones with dropdown menus perfectly. But, one more thing I'm struggling to do is to display numbers I have from a column. I would like to display these as text and numerical values that I can add or subtract to. These are items aswell with Choices function, but it is follow by .Namex0020_Column_x002e__x003a... Would there be anyway to do that?

Comment: Your welcome. Please accept the solution as answer. RE: Numbers: Wrap numerical values with the `Text()` function to turn them to text. Wrap text values in `Value()` function to turn them to numeric.

Comment: PS: Avoid "complex" columns such as Choice, Lookup, Calculated, etc. in Sharepoint altogether (exception: Person-type). They cause more harm than good in PowerApps. Plus, you can handle all the logic in PowerApps itself, no need for complex Sharepoint columns.